# Call parent function inside included/required file

Tags: php, class, include, require

I would like to know if it is possible to call a function of a parent file inside a included file and how that could be work.
For an example we got that:

#### parent_file.php :

```
<?php

    if ( ! class_exists( 'Parent_Class' ) ) {
        class Parent_Class {

            public $id = 10;        


            public static function getInstance() {
                if ( ! ( self::$_instance instanceof self ) ) {
                    self::$_instance = new self();
                }

                return self::$_instance;
            }

            public function init() {            
                include 'child-file.php';

                $child = new Child_Class($id);
                $child->action();
            }

            public function edit($values_of_id) {
                return $values_of_id;
            }

    ?>
```

#### child_file.php :

```
<?php
    if ( ! class_exists( 'Child_Class' ) ) {
        class Child_Class {

            private $id;

            function __construct(){

                $params = func_get_args();

                    if(!empty($params))
                        foreach($params[0] as $key => $param)
                                if(property_exists($this, $key))
                                    $this->{$key} = $param;

                    parent::__construct( array(
                        'id'  => $this->id,
                ) );
            }

            public function action() {
                $url = 'http://myserver.com/edit_child.php?page='. $_REQUEST['page'] .'&action=select&id='. absint($this->id) ) );
                $action = '<a href='. $url .'>Edit</a>'         

                return $action;
            }   

            public function select_table_row() {
                if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && !empty( $_GET['action'] ) )
                    $row = $_GET['id'];

                $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // fictitious params
                $query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = $row";
                $values_of_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                // Call function of parent_file.php
                edit($values_of_id);
            }

            $this->select_table_row();

    ?>
```

This is a fictitious example and I know that the code couldn't work like this. I just want to aim to my question and make my thoughts visual and maybe more comprehensible.

**Important** is that I cannot include parent_file.php in my child_file.php because the Child_Class could be access from multiple files.

I'm sorry if this question was already asked. I'm limited in my buzzwords for this topic and couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the parent class object to the child class, something like this:

```
class parentClass {
    private $str;

    public function __construct($str){
        $this->str = $str;
    }

    public function getChild() {
        $obj = new childClass($this);
        $obj->callParent("send");
    }

    public function send() {
        echo $this->str;
    }
}

class childClass {
    private $parent;

    public function __construct($parent) {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function callParent($method) {
        return $this->parent->$method();
    }
}

$obj = new parentClass("hello");
$obj->getChild(); // prints "hello"
```

Demo: https://eval.in/403427

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Didn't know that I can pass classes as an argument.

Comment: @kindisch: You do not pass a class, but an object ;)